# git clone connection refused

Tags: git, contiki

I'm pretty new and trying to set up an environment for my Econotag.
Using this guide
https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x/wiki/libmc1322x
I am getting an error message .

```
user@instant-contiki:~$ git clone git://git.devl.org/git/malvira/libmc1322x.git
Cloning into 'libmc1322x'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.devl.org:
git.devl.org[0: 209.208.78.21]: errno=Connection refused
```

How to get around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an empty repo (git.devl.org/git/malvira/libmc1322x.git). I think this is the intended replacement https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x.git

```
git clone https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x.git
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

That means that you can't connect to the server over the native git protocol. Note that git native protocol uses ports 9418 TCP and UDP, those might be blocked by some firewall on the way. Or the server itself might be refusing connections. To check for such problems, try cloning a small repository from elsewhere, like `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/editors/uemacs/uemacs.git` (if you love emacs, but hate it's size, it might be for you ;-)

Check that the URL you are giving is right (i.e., `git://` and not e.g. `http://` or something else). Maybe you need to set up an SSH key, an account, or something else first.

Answer (score 3):

Are you working beside a proxy ? 
If yes you might want to try the following commands in your terminal :

```
echo $http_proxy
```

If nothing gets out of that you should reconfigure your .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with RIOT-OS, substituting git: with http: worked!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem I tried all nothing worked later on I come to know there is problem on server. 
Please check basic things before trying other experiments that might save your time.

Comment: Well, this original question is 3 years old and i did not try an Experiment but followed the developers guide. Question is already solved, only the link within the guide was outdated. Without offense, I think you haven't really read the question and answers, before posting here