# Cannot Clone WordPress Submodule in live server

Tags: wordpress, git, github, deployment

While i try to clone my repo from bitbucket to my live site the submodule didn't clone

```
remote: Counting objects: 3638, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3337/3337), done.
remote: Total 3638 (delta 319), reused 3557 (delta 238)
Receiving objects: 100% (3638/3638), 82.65 MiB | 18.15 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (319/319), done.
Submodule 'wp' (git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git) registered for path 'wp'
Cloning into 'wp'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection refused

Clone of 'git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git' into submodule path 'wp' failed
```

Comment: There are a couple of posts and threads dealing with Connection refused error. Have you tried some of them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953806/github-ssh-via-public-wifi-port-22-blocked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837429/git-clone-connection-refused

Comment: Did you try to change the submodule url (http://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309) to https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git?

Answer (score 0):

@jruizaranguren @VonC  Thanks alot it solve my issue by changing path in `.gitmodule`